# how to change the width on an html cell

Tags: html, css

I have a html table which I would like to control the sizes of the cell manually. I am getting confused about how its supposed to work.
First of all, there is a css attribute "table-layout" which is supposed to control whether or not the cell size is automatically set to the largest content in the column or to a fixed size. I tried setting the css width for the td elements using both table-layout=auto and =fixed, and both times the content shrinked from its original size. The problem is that it didn't shrink to the size I wanted to using either value for table-layout. 
Here is my css code:

```
table {table-layout:fixed;}
tr, td {border-style:solid;
  border-width:2px;}
.coursename{width:50px;}
.startdate {width:5px;} 
.isbn{width:10px;}
.author {width:20px;}
.booktitle{width:10px;}
```

Second of all, what exactly are the rules for a automatic table layout? If the content of all the table cells together go past the size of the page, are there certain columns which will shrink first? Will they shrink at all?

Comment: Can you post sample html with content example? It's hard to find the solution with css alone.

Answer (score 1):

One idea that might help is, if you have a link in each cell for example, set the link like this:

```
a { display: block; width: 30px; }
```

Do this for every cell in the table row and you will have table cells with fixed widths. Provided that you fixed the width of the table as well... :)

Answer (score 0):

I am still unsure what your problem is, but you could try
    {table-layout:inherit;}
This should get the size from the parent element.
Also, you could insert the css element into the html and have it override any other elements by preceding it with a !
    {class="!width:300px;"}

Hope this helps.